# i am getting this type of error while running the program of recycle view in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.example.spammessagedetector, PID: 2137
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.spammessagedetector/com.example.spammessagedetector.Inbox}:
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
 androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener)'
 on a null object reference
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
 androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener)'
 on a null object reference
         at com.example.spammessagedetector.Inbox.onCreate(Inbox.java:76)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

here is the code for    Inbox.java

```
package com.example.spammessagedetector;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.view.ActionMode;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.spammessagedetector.R;
import com.example.spammessagedetector.adapter.MessagesAdapter;
import com.example.spammessagedetector.helper.DividerItemDecoration;
import com.example.spammessagedetector.model.Message;
import com.example.spammessagedetector.network.ApiClient;
import com.example.spammessagedetector.network.ApiInterface;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class Inbox extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, MessagesAdapter.MessageAdapterListener{

    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MessagesAdapter mAdapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private ActionModeCallback actionModeCallback;
    private ActionMode actionMode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inbox);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        if (fab != null)
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        mAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(this, messages, this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        actionModeCallback = new ActionModeCallback();

        // show loader and fetch messages
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getInbox();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    /**
     * Fetches mail messages by making HTTP request
     * url: https://api.androidhive.info/json/inbox.json
     */
    private void getInbox() {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        ApiInterface apiService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<List<Message>> call = apiService.getInbox();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Message>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Message>> call, Response<List<Message>> response) {
                // clear the inbox
                messages.clear();

                // add all the messages
                // messages.addAll(response.body());

                // TODO - avoid looping
                // the loop was performed to add colors to each message
                for (Message message : response.body()) {
                    // generate a random color
                    message.setColor(getRandomMaterialColor("400"));
                    messages.add(message);
                }

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Message>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch json: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * chooses a random color from array.xml
     */
    private int getRandomMaterialColor(String typeColor) {
        int returnColor = Color.GRAY;
        int arrayId = getResources().getIdentifier("mdcolor_" + typeColor, "array", getPackageName());

        if (arrayId != 0) {
            TypedArray colors = getResources().obtainTypedArray(arrayId);
            int index = (int) (Math.random() * colors.length());
            returnColor = colors.getColor(index, Color.GRAY);
            colors.recycle();
        }
        return returnColor;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // swipe refresh is performed, fetch the messages again
        getInbox();
    }

    @Override
    public void onIconClicked(int position) {
        if (actionMode == null) {
            actionMode = startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback);
        }

        toggleSelection(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onIconImportantClicked(int position) {
        // Star icon is clicked,
        // mark the message as important
        Message message = messages.get(position);
        message.setImportant(!message.isImportant());
        messages.set(position, message);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageRowClicked(int position) {
        // verify whether action mode is enabled or not
        // if enabled, change the row state to activated
        if (mAdapter.getSelectedItemCount() > 0) {
            enableActionMode(position);
        } else {
            // read the message which removes bold from the row
            Message message = messages.get(position);
            message.setRead(true);
            messages.set(position, message);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Read: " + message.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRowLongClicked(int position) {
        // long press is performed, enable action mode
        enableActionMode(position);
    }

    private void enableActionMode(int position) {
        if (actionMode == null) {
            actionMode = startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback);
        }
        toggleSelection(position);
    }

    private void toggleSelection(int position) {
        mAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
        int count = mAdapter.getSelectedItemCount();

        if (count == 0) {
            actionMode.finish();
        } else {
            actionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(count));
            actionMode.invalidate();
        }
    }


    private class ActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_action_mode, menu);

            // disable swipe refresh if action mode is enabled
            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_delete:
                    // delete all the selected messages
                    deleteMessages();
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mAdapter.clearSelections();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
            actionMode = null;
            recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mAdapter.resetAnimationIndex();
                    // mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // deleting the messages from recycler view
    private void deleteMessages() {
        mAdapter.resetAnimationIndex();
        List<Integer> selectedItemPositions =
                mAdapter.getSelectedItems();
        for (int i = selectedItemPositions.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            mAdapter.removeData(selectedItemPositions.get(i));
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

activity_inbox.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:mContext=".Inbox">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:onClick="floatbuttonclick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit_white_24dp"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.spammessagedetector">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <!-- <activity android:name=".Inbox"></activity> -->
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Profile" />
        <activity android:name=".Splash" />
        <activity android:name=".Inbox">


            <!-- android:theme="@style/splash" -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You try to set an OnRefreshListener on an object called swipe_refresh_layout, but the swipe_refresh_layout is not in the XML.

Comment: According to error log you are not insitiallizing of `swipe refresh layout` and `swipe refresh layout` is not present in `XML`

Comment: 1. You are using setContentView() twice in your code. The second call will override and replace your layout. Hence when calling view of earlier layout will create exceptions.
2. You have not included content_main.xml above. Hence not sure you added swipe refresh layout in your XML file.

Please make sure you have added view in your layout and initialized in properly to avoid exception when using them in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

error at this line.Your referenced  id not found on current layout.

```
 swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
```

why call same method multiple time in your activity.may be here miss lead your swipe_refresh_layout id.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inbox);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

by adding internet permission and removing setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); the code gets executed successfully.